# Qt multi-touch events not working with magic trackpad in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, touch, multi-touch

I just recently started working with Qt 4.7.4 64-bit in order to make some cross-platform multi-touch applications. However, I can’t get Qt's touch events working in Mac OS X.

When I build and run my own application or any of the Qt touch demos, including fingerpaint and knobs, it doesn’t work. No touches I perform on the trackpad, be it a single or multiple touches, does anything in the application; no QTouchEvents are received.  I’ve tried on both a Mac Pro with a magic trackpad and a Macbook Air with its build-in multi-touch trackpad, and in both Snow Leopard and Lion.

Qt's documentation doesn't make any mention of these demos, or QTouchEvents in general, not working in OS X, and implies that they do.  And in my searches for a solution, I have seen videos of Qt's multi-touch working on Mac OS X, and found other people talking about using it, so there must be some way to get this to work.

Does anyone have any idea what’s going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I solved this by updating to Qt 4.8.0.  After doing so multi-touch just started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try link Cocoa framework to your application, it can fix some strange behaviour with events on MacOS X.

Comment: Gave it a shot, but it didn't make any difference. :-(